# Use another AppleID in iOS 7.1.2 AppStore?

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, apple-id

I use iOS 7.1.2 on my iPhone 4 and I would like to change my AppleID for the AppStore. **In "Preferences** > iTunes & AppStore", I already **logged in with my new AppleID**, and when relaunching Preferences, I am still logged in with my new AppleID.

But when trying to update an App **from AppStore**, I am supposed to type in the password for the **old AppleID**.
I cannot find anything in AppStore to change the AppleID directly.

Is there anything I forgot to do?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the app using the Apple ID it was installed with.

For example, say if I install app A with Apple ID B, then sign out and in using Apple ID C, to update app A I need to use Apple ID B.

The most optimal solution to this is re-installing the app on the new Apple ID after saving snaps backing up any data.

From the comments:

> Note that this may require paying for apps and in-app purchases again. You can avoid this in some (but not all) cases by setting up [family sharing](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/) between the two Apple IDs.

Comment: Note that this may require paying for apps and in-app purchases again. Once purchased, an app is "owned" by the Apple ID it was purchased under, and cannot be transferred. You can avoid paying again in some (but not all) cases by setting up [family sharing](https://www.apple.com/family-sharing/) between the two Apple IDs.

Comment: OK, the app I'm talking about is freeware, but otherwise this would be important. Well, then I should uninstall the app and after that reinstall it with the new ID?

Comment: @ferdi2003 Yes, but if there's any data in the app, you should make sure that's backed up first because it'll be deleted along with the original copy of the app.